# Using the bang(!) operator in VB6 to return an object in C# dll

Tags: c#, vb6

With ADO there is the recordset object which allows you to iterate through rows showing getting values from columns in this way...

```
Do While Not someRecordSet.EOF 
    If someRecordSet!ColumnName <> "" Then
        ' do some logic
    End If
Loop
```

I'm wondering how to implement that same behavior (even though the "!" is very much so not recommended to be used) in my own C# dll.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: In C# with ADO.Net, `rs["column_name"]` (use string column name in indexer). Same can be done in VB.Net without the `!`. This is a basic  question in using ADO.Net, which is covered in many examples, not really about “return[ing] an object”.

Comment: https://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2003/12/say_no_to_the_v.html - details on the `!` operator and “how to translate”. Almost 2 decades old..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to define an indexer that works the same way

```
public object this[string param] {
    get {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(param))
            return "";
        return dict[param];
    }
    set {
        dict[param] = value;
    }
}
```